# J Unit Test Case Did not give coverage even when passed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i am writing test case for partial update or Patch call service method.
but i am having problem that the Unit test passes but it is not giving the coverage.

[image: partial Method]

and also it is giving coverage to the methods inside this function.

[image: The Mapping Method]

the test case i have written is as follow

```
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
@Test
public void updateProductPartialTest() throws Exception {
    Product prod = saveprod();
    ProductDto dto = saveDto();
    PartialProductDto updto = patchDto();
    Product upprod = upprod();
    ProductDto updtoo = updateDto();
    
    String id = "5e7e2fcf-c0b8-4c9b-860b-55d71a3c580f";
    given(mapper.ProductDtotoProduct(dto)).willReturn(prod);
    given(mapper.ProductToProductDto(prod)).willReturn(dto);
    given(productrepository.findByProductId(dto.getProductId())).willReturn(Optional.empty());
    given(productrepository.save(prod)).willReturn(prod);
    service.addProduct(dto);
    given(productrepository.findByProductId(dto.getProductId())).willReturn(Optional.of(prod));

    given(service.mappingForPatrialUpdate(updto, prod)).willReturn(upprod);
    
    Mockito.doReturn(updtoo).when(service).updateProductPartial(updto, id);
    given(mapper.ProductToProductDto(prod)).willReturn(dto);
    given(mapper.ProductDtotoProduct(dto)).willReturn(prod);
    given(service.addProduct(dto)).willReturn(dto);
    service.addProduct(dto);
    service.updateProductPartial(updto, id);
    given(productrepository.findByProductId(id)).willReturn(Optional.of(upprod));
    assertThat(productrepository.findByProductId(id).get().equals(upprod));
    
}
```

and the things that i am mocking are :

```
    @Mock
ProductRepository productrepository;
@Mock
SimpleProductdtoProductMapper mapper;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
ProductServiceImpl service;
@InjectMocks
ProductGetServiceImpl serviceget;
```

As far as i understand is this issue is caused by following line:

```
        Mockito.doReturn(updtoo).when(service).updateProductPartial(updto, id);
```

what can i replace this line with so i get coverage to these test.
any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Coverage comes up green when all your possible `If-else` and other line of code is executed. You may have to write positive and negative cases for the same as not all situations would cover all lines! Also, Check if you have Jacoco plugin defined in your POM xml ! To add, coverage should not be the motive of writing tests but if coverage is still a matter, I suggest you write dummy tests which will make compiler reach uncovered lines ! Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for writing back i will try this.